# WP_Query with ajax handler returns the same posts

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery

I have a problem that is getting me bald atm. I have a ajax call that handles a loop that handles some querys and returns posts for me.

So far so good, but the first time the user sees the page we should load 10 posts, and then we want to click a button to request 5 more.

So far so good.

But when we request the 5 more posts we get the 5 first posts again.

My batchloop

```
<?php   
// Our include  
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);  
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');  

// Our variables  
$posts = (isset($_GET['numPosts'])) ? $_GET['numPosts'] : 0;  
$page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;  
$category = (isset($_GET['category_name'])) ? $_GET['category_name'] : 0;  

var_dump($posts);

$args = array(  
    'posts_per_page' => $posts,
    'category_name'  => $category, 
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'paged'          => $page 
);

query_posts($args);  

// $query = new WP_query($args);

// our loop  
if (have_posts()) {  

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts($args);

       while (have_posts()){  
              the_post();  

              get_template_part( 'thumbs', get_post_format() );  
       }  
} 

// unset($page, $posts, $category);

// wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Does anybody sees what im doing wrong?

EDIT:

batch handler

```
 function _batchhandler() { 
        var getamount = localStorage.getItem('amount'); 

        console.log('amount of posts to retrive ' + JSON.parse(getamount));

        // Ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                posts: getamount, 
                page: page,
                category: 'work'
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            url: 'http://dev.xxx.se/wp-content/themes/xxx/batch.php',
            beforeSend: function() {
                _setHeader;
                if( page != 1 ) {
                    console.log('Loading');
                    // Show the preloader
                    $('body').prepend('<div class="preloader"><span class="rotate"></span></div>');
                }
                // If we reach the end we hide the show more button
                if( page >= total ) {
                    $('.load').hide();
                }
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(page);  
                var scroll = ($('.thumb').height() * posts);
                // If thumbs exist append them
                if( data.length ) { 
                    // Append the data
                    $('#batch').append(data);

                    // Remove the crappy width and height attrs from the image * Generated by WP *
                    $('img').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');

                    // Animate each new object in a nice way
                    (function _showitem() {
                        $('#batch .thumb:hidden:first').addClass('show', 80, _showitem);

                        // On the last request do load any more
                        loading = false;  
                    })();

                    // Remove the preloader
                    $('.preloader').fadeOut(200, function() {
                        $('.preloader').remove();   
                    });
                }
                // return false;
            },
            complete: function() {
                // Delete storage
                localStorage.clear();

                // Update the scroller to match the updated content length
                if (scroller)
                    setTimeout("scroller.refresh()", 300);

                // Initalize the load more button
                _clickhandler();
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('No page found');
            }
        });
    }
```

and my load more button function

```
 $('.load').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            // Delete storage
            localStorage.clear();

            if(!loading) {
                loading = true;
                // Increase our pagenumber per click
                page++;
                count++;
                // Remove preloader
                $('.preloader').remove();

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#batch').css({
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translateY(-' + ($('#batch li').outerHeight() * count)  + 'px)'
                    });
                }, 30);

                // Clear storage and set a new
                localStorage.setItem('amount', JSON.stringify(amount.medium));
                var getamount = localStorage.getItem('amount');

                // Send the request to the handler                  
                _batchhandler(page);    
            }      

        });
```

Everything seems fine, the first 10 (1-10) posts loads as the should, but the first time "load more" is clicked we get the next 5 results but the results are posts that loaded the first time (5-10). If we click the "load more" again, we get the correct result

Comment: that should work, could you paste the JS you're using aswell?

Comment: In the future, redirect all your AJAX calls to admin-ajax. It has many benefits esp for security. just a remark.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have defined a start value for page, set it to 1 at the start of your script so when it increments on click it goes to page 2. Otherwise it'll just get the first page.

Comment: No that is set, and a increase the page everytime the load more button is clicked.

Everything works except that the first time load more is clicked we get the same result

Comment: OK, but it's not set in the code you have posted and the fact that it works on a second click would suggest it's retrieving page one on the first click, page 2 on the second - when what you want is to get page 2 on the first click.

Comment: that is what is happen, 
this is my log
ONLOAD
amount of posts to retrive 10
page 1
ONCLICK (FIRST)
amount of posts to retrive 5 
Loading 
page 2

Comment: Are you sure you run _batchhandler() on page load and aren't just leaving it to the first click, that's what it looks like from the code you have submitted.

Comment: I don't know how much more I can help based on the code you've posted. Only to say, read about using AJAX properly in WordPress - http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and be sure to include a nonce (in any case).